# Using a delegate to trigger an event if a panel is visible?

Tags: winforms, events, delegates, panel

I am trying to see a reason to use a delegate, and from what I know, a delegate basically what's for an event.

The event I would have would be in Windows Forms. I have a panel that starts not visible, but when it becomes visible everything in the background becomes disabled (a popup).

I could have it so that whatever makes the panel visible will also cause everything to become disabled, as I usually do.  But could I set up a delegate or an event, so whenever that panel is visible, it calls a method that disables everything?

I just can't figure how to work that out with a delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
panel.VisibleChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (panel.Visible) // Just become visible
    {
        // Disable everything else
    }
};
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot, looks good though.  Would this be considered an event? or what do you call this sort of procedure?

Comment: @Johnny: That's attaching a handler to the VisibleChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Windows.Forms.Control`s (including Panels) have a VisibleChanged event you can bind to. So

```
myPanel.VisibleChanged += OnMyPanelVisibleChanged;
```

Or inline:

```
myPanel.VisibleChanged += (sender, e) => this.Enabled = myPanel.Visible;
```

Comment: All `Control`s  have `VisibleChanged`

Comment: going from the first one, I would have a method called OnMyPanelVisibleChanged()?

Comment: Yes. That takes two arguments (object sender, EventArgs e)